# How to handle multiple expiry dates of the same barcoded items in inventory

Tags: c#, sql, barcode, inventory, stock

I have made a Software for Retailer Shops and I have a problem in handling the expiry dates of the products. The problem is each product of the same brand have the same barcode so they have the same barcode but different expiry. If I add these product separately in the database then how would i sale it in Sale Point portion. They only scan the product via barcode and do not provide any additional information like (batch etc) in sale point.
Any Suggestion will be highly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Normally, a product (e.g. DVDs) has different release dates because of the country it is being shipped to. In which case you need to store the release dates against both the barcode **and** the shipping country.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am talking about daily grossery items who have  expiry dates and all  of them have the same barcode if they are of the same brand. for example 'Pepsi 1.5 letter' has the same bar code everywhere now how can I differentiate among 'Pepsi 1.5 letter' that which one has sold out as they scan only the barcode.

Comment: Ah - I see. I am not an expert, but it doesn't look like it would be possible without having different barcodes for each products expiry date. For example, GS1 barcodes include an expiry date, but if the system is not set up for them, then you can't use that. Either that or the barcode would need to point to an expiry date. But each of those options would require different barcodes for each sku. Sorry. I have no further ideas.

Comment: hmmm its looks like we have to generate our own Barcode for each item.
BTW Thanks for your help!